# How many tempDB data files required in a temp DB and is there any Microsoft recommendation for the same?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Microsoft SQL Server 2016 - How many tempDB data files required in a temp DB and is there any Microsoft recommendation for the same ? What the is most effective way of checking number of cores\processors associated with the SQL server instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no absolute rule ! This configuration dépends on the activity of your applications.
If your application is heavelly transactionnal with big datasets and if developpers has widely uses temp tables, cursors and snapshot isolation level, you should have a high number of file, close to the nimber of cores, and sized properly.
If not, 2 or 4 files will be sufficient.